# How can you declare a dictionary with keys of any type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-typescript

I have a dictionary where keys can be any possible value (including dates, objects, etc). I tried declaring it with `{ [x: any ]: number }`, but I get the error "An index signature parameter type must be 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or a template literal type." What would be the best way to approach this in Typescript?

```
// Aggregates the counts for various values of a particular key. Read-only. Does not mutate the dataset.
count = (field: keyof T) => {
    var counter: { [x: any]: number } = {}
    this.data.forEach( x => {
        let value = x[field]
        if( counter[value] ){
            counter[value]++
        }else{
            counter[value] = 1
        }
    })
    return counter
}
```

Comment: dates, objects, etc cannot be used as keys of objects in javascript (and thus in typescript). If you try to do that, the date/object gets converted to a string. So `{ [x: string]: number }` is probably what you want.

Comment: "I have a dictionary where keys can be any possible value (including dates, objects, etc)"  Uh, you really don't, I think.  Object keys in JS can only really be `string` or `symbol` types.  Anything else is coerced to `string` when you use it.  TS allows `number` because it's such a common use case (arrays, mostly).  You should use `Record<PropertyKey, number>` and coerce non-symbols to `String` explicitly, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxDnBm).  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: "*I have a dictionary where keys can be any possible value (including dates, objects, etc).*" no, you don't. *Objects* can only have strings or symbols as keys. TS also recognises numbers in order to validate indexed-array access but JS still transforms any non-Symbol key to a string. So if you try to use any other objects, it's going to be transformed with `toString()` which would most often produce the string `"[object Object]"`. What you probably want is a Map.

Comment: A `Map` instance allows any type as a key, but the use of Map can be confusing, because keys are compared based on strict equality. That means that if you have a key that's a Date (for example), and another Date that appears to be exactly the same day and time, it will not find the entry in the Map because they're two different Date objects.

Comment: Yeah, this is sketchy.  I think we need to see more of a use case here because as written this is almost certainly going to result in undesirable behavior.  OP, does this behave as intended at runtime?  We can use a `Map` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQ8yVW) but this will have the identity issue.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, the use case was to create counters for every type of value that a key takes in an array (e.g. [ { 'a': 123}, {'a': 'Some name'}, { 'a': null }] --> { 123: 1, 'Some Name': 1, null: 1}), so it can also be null, undefined, etc. This snippet is from an older non-TS code base though, but it does work as intended... But yeah, seems like it's because it gets converted to a string under the hood. I think I got Javascript dictionaries mixed up with Python ones somehow and forgot about the string conversion... XD Thanks for clarifying this everyone.

Comment: So should we close this or do you want to write up an answer for yourself or what?

Comment: @jcalz Yep you can go ahead and write an answer and I'll accept it :) The code you wrote for coercing it explicitly solves the problem